# BigQuery stored procedure execute immediate statement with insert not working when inserting into array

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have an issue using BigQuery stored procedure. The problem is when I'm using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. I'm trying to insert it into a table that has an array. So, code is looking like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `project.dataset.procedureName`(in_param1 STRING, in_param2 STRING)
BEGIN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "INSERT INTO `project.dataset.table` (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (?,?,?)" 
    USING @@current_job_id, 'ERROR', (in_param1, in_param2);
END;
```

The table structure is something like:

```
column1 string
column2 string
column3 struct<
  sub_column1 string,
  sub_column2 string
>
```

The issue that is popping up is only:

> The job encountered an internal error during execution and was unable to complete successfully.

Any suggestions on how to solve insert into a table that is containing array as a column? I tried it without inserting it into an array and it works fine.

Also, one side note is that official documentation should better explain how to insert into an array column using SQL statements.

NOTE

I have also tried with annotations that are not using question marks as per official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update, I was being stupid. Solution is to declare a variable of array type, set values to it and then use that variable in insert statement.